# T-SQL Nested Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, subquery, nested

Not being a SQL expert, and also only being semi-competent in CTE, how can I code this statement use the resultset from the following subquery within the main query, as our SQL Server is 2000.

```
declare @subcategoryConcatenate varchar(3999)
set @subcategoryConcatenate = ''

select @subcategoryConcatenate = @subcategoryConcatenate + pumpCategoryName + ',' FROM
(SELECT
            SCD.PUMPCATEGORYNAME,
            SCD.ENGINECATEGORYNAME,
            SCD.DETAILEDDESCRIPTION
FROM PRTTICKHDR PHDR
INNER JOIN BIDHDR BHDR ON PHDR.DELIV_TICKET_NUMBER = BHDR.DTICKET
INNER JOIN PRTTICKITEM PITM ON PHDR.CONNECTION_ID = PITM.CONNECTION_ID AND PHDR.DELIV_TICKET_NUMBER = PITM.DELIV_TICKET_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN SUBCATEGORYDESCRIPTION SCD ON PITM.ITEM = SCD.PUMPCATEGORY
WHERE SCD.pumpCategoryName IS NOT NULL)
subcategoryDescription

select @subcategoryConcatenate
```

---

```
SELECT
            PHDR.CONNECTION_ID AS CONNECTION_ID,
            BHDR.OFFICE AS OFFICE,
            CMP.NAME AS DEPOT,
            CMP.ADDR1 AS DEPOT_ADDR1,
            CMP.ADDR2 AS DEPOT_ADDR2,
            CMP.CITY AS DEPOT_CITY,
            CMP.STATE AS DEPOT_STATE,
            CMP.ZIP AS DEPOT_ZIP,
            CMP.PHONENUM AS DEPOT_PHONE,
            CMP.FAXNUM AS DEPOT_FAX,
            ACT.NAME AS ACTIVITY,
            SAL.SALES_PERSON_NAME AS SALESPERSON,
            BHDR.DTICKET AS DELIV_TICKET_NUMBER,
            BHDR.PO_NUMBER,
            BHDR.CREATED AS CREATED_DATE,
                BHDR.DDATE AS ESTIMATED_START_DATE,
            BHDR.PROJ_STOP_DATE AS PROJECTED_STOP_DATE,
            CUR.ID,
            CUR.CODE,
            CUR.EXCHANGE_RATE,
            CST.TERMS,
            BHDR.ORDBY AS ORDERED_BY,
            PHDR.ORDERED_BY_CONTACT,
            BHDR.ACCT AS ACCOUNT,
            BHDR.NAME AS CUSTOMER,
            BHDR.ADDR1 AS CUST_ADDR1,
            BHDR.ADDR2 AS CUST_ADDR2,
            BHDR.CITY AS CUST_CITY,
            BHDR.STATE AS CUST_STATE,
            BHDR.ZIP AS CUST_ZIP,
            PHDR.SHIP_TO_NAME,
            PHDR.SHIP_TO_ADDR1,
            PHDR.SHIP_TO_ADDR2,
            PHDR.SHIP_TO_CITY,
            PHDR.SHIP_TO_STATE,
            PHDR.SHIP_TO_ZIP,
            PITM.PRINT_SEQUENCE,
            PITM.ITEM,
            PITM.SUBGROUP,
            PITM.DESCRIPTION,
            SCD.PUMPCATEGORYNAME,
            SCD.ENGINECATEGORYNAME,
            SCD.DETAILEDDESCRIPTION,
            PITM.QUANTITY,
            PITM.UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
            PITM.BILLING_LOGIC_TYPE,
            PITM.INVENTORY_TYPE,
            PITM.CHARGEABLE_DAYS,
            PITM.MINIMUM_CHARGE,
            PITM.WEEKLY_CHARGE,
            PITM.MONTHLY_CHARGE,
            PITM.UNINVOICED_NET,
            PITM.UNINVOICED_VAT
FROM PRTTICKHDR PHDR
INNER JOIN BIDHDR BHDR ON PHDR.DELIV_TICKET_NUMBER = BHDR.DTICKET
INNER JOIN PRTTICKITEM PITM ON PHDR.CONNECTION_ID = PITM.CONNECTION_ID AND PHDR.DELIV_TICKET_NUMBER = PITM.DELIV_TICKET_NUMBER
INNER JOIN COMPANY CMP ON BHDR.OFFICE = CMP.OFFICE
LEFT JOIN SUBCATEGORYDESCRIPTION SCD ON PITM.ITEM = SCD.PUMPCATEGORY
INNER JOIN ACTIVITIES ACT ON BHDR.ACTIVITY_ID = ACT.ID
INNER JOIN SALES_PERSON SAL ON BHDR.SALES_PERSON = SAL.SALES_PERSON
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS CST ON BHDR.ACCT = CST.CUSTNUM
INNER JOIN CURRENCY CUR ON CST.CURRENCY_ID = CUR.ID
ORDER BY
            BHDR.DTICKET,
            PITM.PRINT_SEQUENCE
ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2000 doesn't support CTEs.  Your options are to either make a view out of the subquery if it's used a lot, or to do an inline view:

```
select
  .. stuff..
from
  table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on ...stuff...
  join (
    select
       ...
    from
       ...
    where
       ...
  ) inline on ... stuff ...
where
  ....
```

Comment: Struggling to both code it and elicit what I expect to retrieve!

Comment: If possible, can I simply nest in the top query?

Comment: No, you'd probably be better off writing that as a UDF.  A subquery can only have a `select` statement, not be an entire batch.

Answer (score 0):

You need a user-defined function.
From the looks of it, each *PRTTICKITEM* can have more than one *PUMPCATEGORY*?
(The question needs to better explain the desired results.)

In that case, your UDF would look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  GetPumpCategoriesByItem (@ItemID int)

    RETURNS varchar (8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @CategoryList       varchar (8000)
    SET @CategoryList       = NULL  -- MUST be null to avoid leading comma.

    SELECT
        @CategoryList       =  COALESCE (@CategoryList + ', ', '') + SCD.PUMPCATEGORYNAME
    FROM
        SUBCATEGORYDESCRIPTION SCD
    WHERE
        SCD.PUMPCATEGORY    = @ItemID
    ORDER BY
        SCD.PUMPCATEGORYNAME

    RETURN @CategoryList
END
```

.
To use it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    PITM.ITEM,
    dbo.GetPumpCategoriesByItem (PITM.ITEM),
    ... ...
FROM 
    ... ...
INNER JOIN PRTTICKITEM PITM ON ... ...
... ...
```